# single-source shortest algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

Let G = (V, E) be a weighted, directed graph with weight function w : E → R. Give an O(V E)-time algorithm to find, for each vertex v ∈ V , the value δ*(v) = min{u∈V} {δ(u, v)}.

I don't understand  the question. Could someone give me some ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

This basically means:

- `G = (V, E)` having a graph with V vertices and E edges
- `weighted, directed graph with weight function w : E → R` the graph is directed and weighted, where each edge has real value weight
- `O(V E)-time algorithm` find the algorithm that runs in number of operations proportional to number of vertices multiplied by number of edges
- `for each vertex v ∈ V , the value δ*(v) = min{u∈V} {δ(u, v)}` here they have not described what `δ(u, v)` means, but most probably this is the sum of weights of edges from vertex u to v. This basically asks you to find the minimum distance from vertex `u` to all vertices `v`.

And the answer to your question [Bellman Ford.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I know this question may be relevant to Bellman Ford which is a single-source shortest path algorithm. Is the u fixed or we need to consider all u in V? If u is fixed, could you give me more detail to how to modify Bellman Ford to solve this problem?

Comment: Based on my understanding, `u` is fixed. Have you read my link? I believe that no, because if you had you would see that no modifications needed.

Comment: Well, actually I'm doing my homework and really have no idea with this problem. I have thought that this problem is Bellman Ford algorithm. However, this problem is one of the exercises  in the section of Bellman-Ford algorithm. I doubt the meaning of the question because I think it won't be totally same with Bellman Ford it introduced just earlier.